# what is the difference between "struggle for" and "to"?

Tags: prepositions, verbs, infinitives

Is there any difference in meaning between these?

A. struggle for survival

B. struggle to survive

C. struggle  for surviving

Answer (score 1):

You "struggle to" do something. That is, it is followed by a verb. "Struggle to survive", "struggle to win", "struggle to find the peanut butter", etc.

You can "struggle for" an object or an idea. That is, it is followed by a noun. "They struggled for the knife." "He struggled for a solution to the problem". Etc.

I suppose you could say "struggle for surviving" if "surviving" is a gerund. Like, "The struggle for surviving in the arctic often involves ..." That particular example sounds rather awkward to me, but I guess it's grammatically valid.

"Struggle to survive" and "struggle for survival" mean pretty much the same thing. There might be a distinction in context. But it's common in English -- and, I would think, in any language -- that there is more than one way to express the same basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

the words `to` and `for` do not modify `struggle`, they modify `survive`/`survival`.

Here is the breakdown of how they're different.

- **for survival:**  `for` is a preposition, and `survival` is an accusative noun.  `for survival` means that the reason for the `struggle` has something to do with `survival`
- **to survive:**  `to survive` is an infinitive verb.

In the end, you essentially get the same meaning.